# Determine which gems are not being used in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Hey fellow stackerenos!

I'm working on a massive Rails 2.3.18 app with 90 gems in the Gemfile and 60 vendor plugins.

What's the best systematic way to determine which gems/plugins I don't need anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Remove a gem, run your test suite. If it fails, you still need that gem. If not, you may not need it anymore. I recommend further investigation before you remove it, maybe some code you haven't tested requires it.